# Protected method not Inherited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I'm making a change to an API so the new version is being namespaced under an `Api::V2` module. The old API was just under the `API` namespace. I want to be able to inherit and overwrite some of the things from the old controller.

It works fine if I do this:

```
module Api
  module V2
    class ResourcesController < ::Api::ResourcesController 
      include Crud
```

The parent class, `::Api::ResourcesController` defines a `model` method, which is used here in the `options` method and also required by the `::Api::Crud` module.

```
# app/controllers/resources_controller.rb
protected

  def model
    Resource
  end

# app/controllers/concerns/api/crud.rb
def model
  raise "Model must be defined"
end
```

However, the changes I need to make are in that `Crud` module, so I created a namespaced version of that module.

```
# app/controllers/concerns/api/v2/crud.rb
module Api
  module V2
    module Crud
      include ::Api::Crud
      include ::Api::V2::ReadOnly
```

So this new module is still using that `model` method that raises an error if it isn't defined, by including it from `::Api::Crud`. Now, when I try to use this new module in my controller:

```
# app/controllers/api/vw/resources_controller.rb
module Api
  module V2
    class ResourcesController < ::Api::ResourcesController 
      include ::Api::Crud
```

I get the error, `Model must be defined`. Why is it not able to find the `model` method defined in my parent controller class?

Answer (score 3):

If you do

```
class Base
end

module Special
end

class Derived < Base
  include Special
end
```

Then `Derived.ancestors` is `[Derived, Special, Base, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

i.e. when looking for a method, ruby first looks in `Derived`, then the module `Special`, then `Base`.

It's not that ruby can't find the `model` method in the parent controller class, it's that search order finds the version from the module first.

Comment: I wish I could +2 this answer.  Awesomely clear explanation @FrederickCheung!

Comment: That does make sense. Do you have any suggestions to work around this other than removing the `model` method that raises an error from the module? It's nice to have some kind of validation to make it clear when the module expects certain methods on the class that implements it.

Comment: You could use the self.included hook on the module to define the stub method only if that method doesn't already exist. A completely different take is to have some shared specs/tests (like ActiveModel::Lint) that validate that this class implements the interface it should.